# link and image not work together

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider, anchor

It is working perfect without anchor tag but, When i put the anchor tag before image tag  , to make image link, It show only one image. 
demo link: http://jsfiddle.net/vrD2C/

Javascript code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#photos a img:gt(0)").hide();
    setInterval(function() {
        var current = $('#photos a img:visible');
        var next = current.next().length ? current.next() : $('#photos a img:eq(0)');
        current.fadeOut();
        next.fadeIn();
    }, 3000);

});
```

HTML CODE:

```
<div id="photos">
    <a href="advertise.php">
        <img src="images/in-the-outfield.jpg" />
    </a>
    <a href="advertise.php">
        <img src="images/ballpark-scoreboard.jpg" />
    </a>
    <a href="advertise.php">
        <img src="images/batting-helmets.jpg" />
    </a>
    <a href="advertise.php">
        <img src="images/baseball-in-glove.jpg" />
    </a>
</div>
```

Comment: Rephrase your question, its unclear what's the problem?

Comment: demo link: http://jsfiddle.net/vrD2C/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `a` instead of `img` in your selectors.

*HTML*

```
<div id="photos">
    <a href="advertise.php">
        <img src="http://imagefader.s3.amazonaws.com/0.jpg" />
    </a>
    <a href="advertise.php">
        <img src="http://imagefader.s3.amazonaws.com/1.jpg" />
    </a>
</div>
```

*Script*

```
$(function () {
    $("#photos a:gt(0)").hide(); //Updated selector here
    $("#photos a:first").addClass("shadow"); //Updated selector here
});

function next() {
    var $currentImage = $("#photos a:visible"); //Updated selector here
    var $nextImage = $currentImage.next();
    if ($nextImage.length == 0) {
        $nextImage = $("#photos a:first"); //Updated selector here
    }
    swapImage($currentImage, $nextImage);
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/satpalsingh/zgjatyaf/1/)